# Ошибка OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32. Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\Project python\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win64.zip')
browser.get('http://selenium.dev/')
```

Хочу спарсить сайт, для этого нужна подгрузка страницы с ajar, поэтому вопрос, что это за ошибка и как это исправить?

```
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\Project python\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win64.zip')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project python\Parser Dns.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\Project python\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win64.zip')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: geckodriver-v0.32.0-win64.zip, а желательно .exe. Распакуйте архив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Насколько я понимаю вы дали не правильный путь к файлу, он у вас запакован*

`'D:\Project python\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win64.zip'`

```
                                             ↑
```

*Пример:*

`'D:\Project python\название_драйвера.exe'`